# Getting the path back from SHGetKnownFolderPath in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, marshalling

Trying to use SHGetKnownFolderPath API to return the path of the Downloads folder in VB.Net. I'm able to call the function and get a pointer to the result, but I'm flummoxed on the proper way to get this into a VB.Net string to work with. (I understand CopyMemory is not the way to go, but I can't seem to make sense of the Marshalling methods).

<< Edited to show final code >>

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("shell32.dll")>
Private Function SHGetKnownFolderPath(
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal rfid As Guid,
    ByVal dwFlags As UInt32,
    ByVal hToken As IntPtr,
    ByRef pszPath As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function

Public Function GetDownloadsFolder() As String

    Dim Result As String = ""
    Dim ppszPath As IntPtr
    Dim gGuid As Guid = New Guid("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")

    If SHGetKnownFolderPath(gGuid, 0, 0, ppszPath) = 0 Then
        ' ----
        ' Question was: what goes here? Answer follows:
        '
        Result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszPath)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)
        ' ---
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```

Comment: Everything if OK, just declare pszPath as IntPtr. When SHGetKnownFolderPath returns, use Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr) to get the string. Don't forget to call CoTaskMemFree.

Answer (score 2):

Alex F gets credit for providing the crucial info-- here's the final code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("shell32.dll")>
Private Function SHGetKnownFolderPath(
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal rfid As Guid,
    ByVal dwFlags As UInt32,
    ByVal hToken As IntPtr,
    ByRef pszPath As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function

Public Function GetDownloadsFolder() As String

    Dim Result As String = ""
    Dim ppszPath As IntPtr
    Dim gGuid As Guid = New Guid("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")

    If SHGetKnownFolderPath(gGuid, 0, 0, ppszPath) = 0 Then
        Result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszPath)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```